# Is it possible to save edits in the R DT package

Tags: r, dt

The most recent version of the [DT package](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) allows editing

I was hoping that you could use the table visually to replace values in the underlying data.frame as a swift option to coding such as:-

```
df[1,2] <- 76
df[63,45] <- "foo"
```

But this does not seem to be the case. Am I missing something? Or is this a potential enhancement. Edit+save seems the obvious usage

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking and your example isn't reproducible. What do you actually get? What do you expect to get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***"But this does not seem to be the case. Am I missing something?"***

From what I understand, you want to visually replace some value in your data frame but you have not succeeded. I am not sure what you have tried but this is what I have done and it works for me in RStudio.

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris)
DT::datatable(head(iris), editable = TRUE)
```

**Edit:**

OP's question was unclear to me. He/she has made it clear that is it possible to save once editing any value. I could not find anything within the DT package as such, if that is what is expected. However, there are a few workarounds for editing a dataframe via a GUI.

1) editData package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/editData/README.html

2) Assigning the dataframe as `df <- edit(df)` opens up a GUI which can be edited and just closed, it saves the state of the dataframe. While I cross checked this feature, the source of this answer is from here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206908027-Data-Editor-GUI-modifying-values-Feature-and-Error-

Feel free to add a solution pertaining to DT package if found.

Comment: Please read title  Is it possible to save edits in the R DT package

Comment: Apologies, my bad. I updated the answer with some alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I'll check it out